# Count not showing correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables on different databases.  I am trying to find the differences in the number of records.  So far I have tried:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from tabel1 a1 
where not exists 
(
  select * 
  from db2.table1 a2 
  where a1.id = a2.id
);
```

Which returns `31298`.  But if I run the count on the tables by them selves I get the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 --  227429 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.Table1 --  256406
```

Which is a difference of `28977` records.  Can anyone see what I am doing that would cause the difference in counts?

**UPDATE**

I am aware I can determine the difference by subtracting the counts.  What I'm wondering is if it's possible to get an accurate difference using `not exists`.  This is a simplified version of a more complex query.

Comment: Could you have duplicate ids in either of the tables?  This would explain it.

Comment: You appear to be counting the difference in matching `id`s rather than the difference in the number of records. For example, both tables could have the same number of records, but if their `id` values are all different you'll get 227429 results.

Comment: You are basically just seeing how often the id field in table1 does not exist in the other table.  This will not necessarily be the difference in record counts.

Comment: They seem to be two entirely different requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are records in table2 that don't have any corresponding entries in table1.

Your inner query only select values in table2 that also correspond to table1.

So if table1 has IDs

```
1
3
5
```

and table 2 has IDs

```
1
3
7
```

you would see count of 1 (id 5) because rows 1 and 3 match, but 7 doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.Table1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying to figure out if I can get the difference using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.  I updated my question.

Comment: Why?  I think you have to update your question with what you are trying to do.  Your question says you are trying to find the differences in the number of records.  It sounds like perhaps you are looking for something else.  The count of A not in B?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)) - ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.Table1))
```

The one you wrote is something completely different.

**[UPDATE]**

If you are trying to count the number of records in first database that do not exist in the second then your query is correct but your assessment is incorrect. You can't compare the result of arithmetic subtract with set subtract. They are totally different concepts.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying to figure out if I can get the difference using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the sample data

DB1.TBL

```
╔════╦══════════════════╗
║ ID ║       Name       ║
╠════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ invisal          ║
║  2 ║ Thomas Jones-Low ║
║  4 ║ Mehran           ║
║  6 ║ Abe Miessler     ║
╚════╩══════════════════╝
```

DB2.TBL

```
╔════╦══════════════════╗
║ ID ║       Name       ║
╠════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ invisal          ║
║  2 ║ Thomas Jones-Low ║
║  3 ║ Gordon Linoff    ║
║  8 ║ Martijn Pieters  ║
╚════╩══════════════════╝
```

The definition of **"differences in the number of records"** can mean many things. For example,

- If you talk about **"difference total number of row"**, then DB1.TBL and DB2.TBL has the difference of 0.

> ```
> SELECT
> ABS((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB1.TBL) -
>     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.TBL))
> ```

- If you talk about **"number of different records"**, then there are 4

> ```
> SELECT
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB1.TBL) +
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.TBL) -
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
>  DB1.TBL INNER JOIN DB2.TBL 
>  ON DB1.TBL.id = DB2.TBL.id
> ) * 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your db2.table1 likely has a few ids that do not exist in db1. Hence it is showing fewer differences in row count difference.
e.g. db1.table1 has

```
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Banana
```

db2.table1 has

```
1 Apple
4 Pineapple
```

Your first query will return a result of 2.
Your row count comparison will return 1

Interestingly, note that your row count difference will never be higher than your first query result.